# Julia - trying to compare two strings

Tags: julia

I am trying to compare two strings I got as input, but it printed at me an error like "syntax: unexpected "="".

```
x = readline()
y = readline()

y = println(cmp(y, "Ciao"))
x = println(cmp(x, "Ciao"))


    
if  x=1
    println("Ho fatto un confronto in modo giusto")

elseif x=0
    println("No simone, non hai inserito quello che mi aspettavo")

elseif y=1
    println("Hai inserito la y e l'ho controllata, il programma funziona")

elseif y=0
    println("No simone, non hai inserito quello che mi aspettavo")

else println("Il programma non ha funzionato")
   
end 

return x,y
```

Comment: Benvenuto Simone. Non si capisce molto cosa vuoi ottenere - it is not so clear what you are trying to achieve in the script

Comment: Buongiorno, ho risolto ma grazie di aver risposto, cercherò di essere più chiaro in futuro

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Julia, you should use `==` for comparison: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/mathematical-operations/#Numeric-Comparisons

This is different from assignment operator `=`, so for example

```
# Assignment
julia> x = 1
1

# Comparison
julia> x == 1
true
```

Also: `println` returns `nothing` so this code still wouldn’t work even with that fix. If you delete the calls to `println` and fix the assignments to be equality checks, then the code might work.